# Android Press LongClickListener get X, Y Coordinates, OnTouchListener

Tags: android

I have a button and want to use a LongClickListener, to get by pressing on the button the coordinates during changing the position of the button. How can I get in a LongClickListener or perhaps other Method the X,Y coordinates of the Click/Mouse.

I tried it with an OnTouchListener, that is working. But the problem is that the TouchListener reacts on each click and not how I want only on pressed.

Answer (score 14):

do it like here in OnTouchListener:

```
OnTouchListener mOnTouch = new OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {            
       final int action = ev.getAction();
       switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
          final int x = (int) ev.getX();
          final int y = (int) ev.getY();
       break;
    }
};
```

Comment: noo thats not that what i want. I want pressed not each click

Comment: Use these coordinates inside your OnLongClickListener

Comment: @Richard OnLongClickListener does not provide coordinates in its callback

Answer (score 4):

You have to store the last known coordinates as found in onTouch somewhere (global data for example) and read them in your onLongClick method.

You may also have to use **onInterceptTouchEvent** in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to

- Add a class variable to store the coordinates
- Save the X,Y coordinates using an `OnTouchListener`
- Access the X,Y coordinates in the `OnLongClickListener`

The other two answers leave out some details that might be helpful, so here is a full demonstration:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // class member variable to save the X,Y coordinates
    private float[] lastTouchDownXY = new float[2];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // add both a touch listener and a long click listener
        View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
        myView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        myView.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    }

    // the purpose of the touch listener is just to store the touch X,Y coordinates
    View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            // save the X,Y coordinates
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                lastTouchDownXY[0] = event.getX();
                lastTouchDownXY[1] = event.getY();
            }

            // let the touch event pass on to whoever needs it
            return false;
        }
    };

    View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            // retrieve the stored coordinates
            float x = lastTouchDownXY[0];
            float y = lastTouchDownXY[1];

            // use the coordinates for whatever
            Log.i("TAG", "onLongClick: x = " + x + ", y = " + y);

            // we have consumed the touch event
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have written a class to do this.
use:

```
new SetOnLongTouch(tv_main, new SetOnLongTouch.onLongTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLongTouch(View v, float X,float Y) {
                Log.d("TEST","X:" + X + " Y:" + Y);
            }
});
```

Class:

```
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

class SetOnLongTouch {
    View view;
    private float[] lastTouchDownXY = new float[2];
    onLongTouchListener listener;
    SetOnLongTouch(View v,onLongTouchListener onLongTouchListener){
        view = v;
        listener = onLongTouchListener;
        v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    lastTouchDownXY[0] = motionEvent.getX();
                    lastTouchDownXY[1] = motionEvent.getY();
                }else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    view.performClick();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                listener.onLongTouch(view,lastTouchDownXY[0],lastTouchDownXY[1]);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    public interface onLongTouchListener{
        void onLongTouch(View v, float X, float Y);
    }
}
```

if you are a newbie like me then it also gives you the idea that how these listener works and how,why and where use interfaces.